# Best practice to vstack multiple large np.arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have 4 numpy.arrays: X1, X2, X3, X4; each shape: 60000,700.

I would like to put them together in the form

```
X1[0,:]
X2[0,:]
X3[0,:]
X4[0,:]
X1[1,:]
....
```

This should result in an array with the shape: 240000,700.
I tried to do it via vstack in a loop.

```
X = np.empty((0,X1[0,:].shape[0]))
for row in range(X1.shape[0]):
    X = np.vstack((X,X1[row,:],X2[row,:],X3[row,:],X4[row,:]))
```

Is there a faster and or more memory efficient way to do it?

*edit, addition:*
I also have 4 numpy.arrays: y1, y2, y3, y4; each shape: 60000,
which are supposed to be stacked as:

```
y1[0,:]
y2[0,:]
y3[0,:]
y4[0,:]
y1[1,:]
....
```

This should result in an array with the shape: 240000,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.hstack` to horizontally stack and reshape -

```
np.hstack((X1,X2,X3,X4)).reshape(-1,X1.shape[1])
```

Now, `hstack` is built upon `concatenate`. So, we can gain further improvement with its direct usage -

```
np.concatenate((X1,X2,X3,X4),axis=1).reshape(-1,X1.shape[1])
```

Equivalently with `np.stack` -

```
np.stack((X1,X2,X3,X4),axis=1).reshape(-1,X1.shape[1])
```

Comment: super solution! super fast!

Comment: but...I have also vectors (shape: (60000,)). Here your solution does not work, because of "shape". Hardcoding the dimention works of course: .reshape(-1,1). But how can I generalize it?

Comment: @rul30 Can you show with your loopy code how you would like to stack in `(60000,)` shaped array?

Comment: @rul30 Simply skip the reshape for the 1D arrays case.

Comment: @rul30 Use my earlier comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182286/discussion-between-rul30-and-divakar).

Comment: it seems I need to use vstack instead of hstack: y  = np.vstack((y1,y2,y3,y4)).reshape(-1,1)

Comment: @rul30 Yeah if they are 2D arrays with one col each, you would use that.